# Translate Linux 'cut' command to Windows command

Tags: linux, windows, cut

I am running some code which necessitates the usage of the following line exactly:

```
cat data/train.txt | cut -d$'\t' -f 2 | grep -v "^$"| sort | uniq > data/labels.txt
```

Does Anyone know how this line of command can be translated to a Windows command - or what it means?

P.S. I have been trying to run the code through WSL on my Windows, and the line does execute correctly, however the package I'm trying to use necessitates use of Pytorch with GPU access, which WSL does not facilitate, thus the need to use it on the Windows command line

Comment: The command above should work in wsl. It does not require anything special.

Comment: @drescherjm yes the command does work in WSL, however the rest of the installation necessitates using pytorch with GPU, and installing NVDIA drivers through WSL which apparently cannot be done at the moment: https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/3847

Comment: Can't you just do this step in WSL. This is a bit of text manipulation.

Comment: @drescherjm I have, however when I try to access the data from the rfoot folder which is supposed to hold the output and all folders used in WSL, it is not accesible. Is it not possible to translate this command to do the whole thing in windows?

Comment: Maybe a power shell script. This is not easy in plain dos

Comment: @drescherjm that would also work, am able to run powershell - however do not know the equivalent command..

Comment: Besides what previous comments say, the Windows command line is *not* the same as DOS.
You can try installing MinGW or git for Windows. Those give you rather functional versions of Bash without any kind of virtualization.

Comment: you could simply download the unix utilities for Windows: http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/ or http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/ (without the overhead of MinGW)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name would that mean I could use the exact same command in windows cmd ?

Answer (score 0):

The Answer was provided by @a_horse_with_no_name, as downloading the utix utilities for windows from: unxutils.sourceforge.net